# Why this occur an overflow ?

Tags: assembly, stack, buffer-overflow

So i was wondering from some days, how this code cause an overflow:

```
__asm
{
CheckDebugger:
  PUSH EAX                    // Save the EAX value to stack
  MOV EAX, [FS:0x30]          // Get PEB structure address
  MOV EAX, [EAX+0x02]         // Get being debugged byte
  TEST EAX, EAX               // Check if being debuged byte is set
  JNE CheckDebugger           // If debugger present check again
  POP EAX                     // Put back the EAX value
}
```

So, this code is checking the value of BeingDebuggedByte into PEB block .

So, if this one is set, he's going to jump again to CheckDebugger, if not he's going to continue.

So, i'm reading Art of Anti Detection (1), and this document say:

*" if debugger present it will check again until a overflow occurs in stack, when an overflow occurs the stack canaries will trigger an exception and process will be closed, this is the shortest way to exit the program."*

How an overflow can occur in the stack ? Maybe because we are pushing eax everytime into the stack?

Comment: Yes, exactly due to that

Comment: Ok, thanxs @SamiKuhmonen ! I was lost .. ahahah

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original poster answered his own question in the question.

Comment: fun fact: if you would remove debugger in the meantime after already looping once+ time, it may crash anyway, because only single `pop eax` will not restore the stack (although if the final part of function is using common epilogue like `mov esp,ebp ret`, it will survive+restore the unbalanced stack state). If there is restoring epilogue, whoever is debugging this may fool the code after few loops (when he does notice the trap) to think there's no debugger, and rejoin the original code flow.

Answer (score 0):

What's the definition of insanity? Doing the same thing over and over and expecting a different result.

If the `TEST EAX, EAX` tests not equal the first time, it will test not equal every time because you do nothing to change the value you are testing.

On the other hand, each iteration of the loop adds a 32 bit number to the stack when you `push eax` which is why it overflows.

You could jump to the instruction after the `push eax` and then you'll just be in an infinite loop, but another thread might change the variable you are testing and let you out of the loop - if there are other threads.